# JMS: local broker + HA

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

There is a cluster of tomcats, each tomcat node generates "tasks" which can be performed by any other node. I'd prefer task to be performed by the node which created it.

I thought that it would be good idea to use an embedded broker for each tomcat and configure it as a store-and-forward network. The problem is that a node can go down and the tasks/messages should then be performed by other tomcat instead of waiting for current one to get up.

On the other hand - when using master/slave cluster how to prioritize the node which sent the message?

How to configure it in activemq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The priority of a local consumer should be default. [In AMQ Docs](http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-distributed-queues-work.html):

> ActiveMQ uses Consumer Priority so that local JMS consumers are always
>   higher priority than remote brokers in a store and forward network.

However, you will not really achive what you want. If one tomcat node goes down, so will the embedded ActiveMQ (and any messages still attached to that instance). A message will not automatically get copied to all other brokers.

But you ask something about Master/slave cluster. Do you intend to have a network of brokers OR a master/slave setup? Or do you intend to have a combo?

Comment: Right now i'm not sure what I want :) Currently each tomcat adds jobs to a table in a single database and then acquires 1 job at a time. I want to migrate this solution to JMS. I need persistent messages (they must be delivered).